# TextView autolink error

Tags: c#, android, textview, xamarin, autolink

I am using Xamarin and am trying to get the autolink working for a TextView.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace TestTextViewAutoLink
{
    [Activity (Label = "TestTextViewAutoLink", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            TextView textView = new TextView (this.ApplicationContext);
            textView.AutoLinkMask = Android.Text.Util.MatchOptions.PhoneNumbers; 
            textView.Text = "This is a phone number 0800 32 32 32";

            SetContentView(textView);
        }
    }
}
```

The text is being displayed, however the following error occurs when I click on the text:

> Unfortunately, TestTextViewAutoLink has stopped

May I please have some help to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have also tried this code, however the same error occurs:

```
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    TextView textView = new TextView (this.ApplicationContext);
    //textView.AutoLinkMask = Android.Text.Util.MatchOptions.PhoneNumbers; 
    textView.Text = "This is a phone number 0800 32 32 32";

    Linkify.AddLinks(textView, MatchOptions.PhoneNumbers);

    SetContentView(textView);
}
```

Comment: please do like this    myTextView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);..change mail to phone number in linkfy for yours need

Comment: There is no setAutoLinkMask method in the TextView object.

Comment: actually you are doing with c# so less knowledge i have..i am using java max time

Comment: it ma help..http://docs.dot42.com/Reference/P.Android.Widget.TextView.AutoLinkMask ...why you are not doing it all in xml layout on compile time

Comment: I would rather do it via code, and not have to use XML layout. I am interested as to why the error occurs. Also, have a look at my edit.